# passing parameters in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, parameters

I'm new in JSP. My question is about passing a parameter from jsp to web service invocation called in the same jsp page. Here's my code

```
<html>
</head>
<body>
    <h:form id="locate-vehicle">
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td><h:commandButton value="Localiser" action="clientSpace/initialize.js" /                    </td>
        <td>
        <select name="chooseVehicle">
            <c:forEach var="item" items="${HexaBean.allIdVehiculeByUtilisateur}">
            <option><c:out value="${item}"/></option>
            </c:forEach>
            <option>Tous les véhicules</option>
        </select> 
        </td>
        </tr>          
    </table> 
    </h:form>

  <%
   WebServiceClient.GpsWebService_Service service = new   WebServiceClient.GpsWebService_Service();
WebServiceClient.GpsWebService port = service.getGpsWebServicePort();
 // TODO initialize WS operation arguments here
java.lang.String arg0 = request.getParameter("chooseVehicle");
// TODO process result here
double Lat = port.getLastLatitudeByIdVehicule(arg0);
    double Lng = port.getLastLongitudeByIdVehicule(arg0);
  %>  

<div id="map-canvas"/> 
</body>
```

I want to pass "chooseVehicle" as an argument in the web service invocation. My web service gives latitude and longitude as a result.

```
  <%
   WebServiceClient.GpsWebService_Service service = new   WebServiceClient.GpsWebService_Service();
WebServiceClient.GpsWebService port = service.getGpsWebServicePort();
 // TODO initialize WS operation arguments here
java.lang.String arg0 = request.getParameter("chooseVehicle");
// TODO process result here
double Lat = port.getLastLatitudeByIdVehicule(arg0);
    double Lng = port.getLastLongitudeByIdVehicule(arg0);
  %>
```

So in order to obtain that result i need to specify the vehicle id which is in my case contained in a drop down list. the items are retrieved by calling the method "allIdVehiculeByUtilisateur" in my Bean.
I tried this by doing this way 
java.lang.String arg0 = request.getParameter("chooseVehicle");
But that worked only if i seek the parameter from an other jsp page. 
How can i solve this problem please ? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Writing code in JSP is a very bad practice. JSPs are meant for presentation only. Try to move the code to server side and try to debug.